# Attaching independent variable values to data for curve fitting

Tags: list-manipulation, fitting

I have a data set of $10^4$ entries. I want to plot the last $2000$ data with the same argument at $x$ axis and fit a curve. That means the range of $x$ axis will be $8001$ to $10000$ incremented by $1$.

I wrote code like the following to know the coefficient of fitting curve:

```
d = Import["ss.dat"];
T = Table[d[[1, i]], {i, 8001, 10000}];
FindFit[T, a*E^(-b*x), {a, b}, x]
```

`FindFit` returns the values of $a$ and $b$ considering $x$ to range from $1$ to $2000$ instead of $8001$ to $10000$.

If anyone can tell me how to deal with this problem that will be great help.

I am attaching data in the following link:

[data as DAT file in Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OKcfdOf8lpQ_W2YEI6l3KLMlUm0ll5xP)

Comment: You could try `T = Table[{i, d[[1, i]]}, {i, 8001, 10000}];`. This will allow you to give `FindFit` 2D data with the specific x values you want.

Comment: Your first problem has been pointed out by @MassDefect.  But you should linearize your model with the following:  `lmf = LinearModelFit[Transpose[{T[[All, 1]], Log[T[[All, 2]]]}], x, x]
Show[LogPlot[Exp[lmf[x]], {x, 8001, 10000}, 
  PlotStyle -> {LightGray, Thickness[0.03]}],
 ListLogPlot[T, PlotStyle -> Red]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you don't need *nearly* so many points to get a nice fit. Regardless, we can use NonlinearModelFit[] to get what you want:

You can use Drop[list,n] to drop the first n elements of a list.

```
dir = NotebookDirectory[];
SetDirectory[dir];
file = "ss.dat";

d = Import[file];
T = Drop[Flatten[d], 8000];
St = Drop[Take[T, {1, -1, 1}], 0];
Stt = Table[{i, T[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[St]}];
e = NonlinearModelFit[Stt, a*E^(-b*x), {a, b}, x]
e["BestFitParameters"]


GraphicsGrid[{{ListPlot[Stt, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Scientific"], Plot[{Evaluate[a*E^(-b*x) /. e["BestFitParameters"]]}, {x, 0,Length[Stt]}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", Epilog -> {Red, Point[Stt]}]}}]
```

[image: plots]

Using the code will drop every x elements from your entire list, drastically reducing your plot points. 2000, or even 10000 are just not needed.

```
St = Drop[Take[T, {1, -1, 1}], 0];
```

and changing to:

```
St = Drop[Take[T, {1, -1, 40}], 0];
```

Gives us:

[image: plot2]

A nice visual that the points lay directly on our function, and a good fit for a and b.